# How to acess the current position of apply functions inside the scope of the called function?

Tags: r, apply

How to do something like this :

```
library(zoo)
s = sample(1:10,10)
s
# [1]  3  9  1 10  2  8  6  7  4  5
rollapply(s, width=1, function(x) ifelse(x==3|x==4, return(Current_Position), return(NA)) )
```

The output I would like to get is :

```
# [1]  1  NA  NA NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  9  NA
```

i.e. how to get that `Current_Position` value inside the function being called by `rollapply`?

Comment: It says `object 'Current_Position' not found`.

Comment: Try `v1 <- rollapply(s, width=1, FUN= function(x) x==3|x==4) * seq_along(s); is.na(v1) <- v1==0`

Comment: @Pascal yes that's my point I'm giving this code to show what I would like to do but Current_Position isn't defined here. My question is how to get the position of `x` inside of `s`

Comment: So don't provide an output, or specify it is the expected one. As you wrote your question, it seems to work

Comment: Do you need only a solution involving `ifelse` and inside the `rollapply`?

Comment: @akrun it's fine if it's just an if()

Comment: Can you check whether the one I posted as comment work for you.

Comment: @akrun I was able to get what I need with a boolean vector to mark the positions I need with TRUE, thanks

Answer (score 0):

In such cases apply along the index rather than the vector itself:

```
library(zoo)
s <- c(3, 9, 1, 10, 2, 8, 6, 7, 4, 5)
rollapply(seq_along(s), 1, function(ix) if (s[ix] %in% 3:4) ix else NA)
## [1]  1 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA  9 NA
```